# Customizing the columns in a bound grid control?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

When I bind to the GridControl I want to get rid of columns showing something like:
``` System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection``1[Model.PersonEmails] ```

Instead I would like in this case to get the total number of emails based on the parent entity.

Comment: When you say `GridControl` do you mean DataGridView or are you referring to some third-party grid control?

Comment: Use a custom class (like a DTO or even a view model) to contain the data to be shown in the grid. You can create the objects in a linq `Select` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay

I've already found a solution using the GridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText event handler.

Yes, it's third party control.

```
Private Sub GridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CustomColumnDisplayText
    If e.Column.FieldName = "PersonEmails" Then
        Dim Entities = DirectCast(e.Value, System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection(Of PersonEmails))
        If Not Entities Is Nothing Then
            If Entities.Count = 1 Then
                Dim x As PersonEmail = Entities.FirstOrDefault()
                e.DisplayText = x.Email
            Else
                e.DisplayText = Entities.Count
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~